# Sorting an ArrayList object populated with custom objects with two data fields each

Tags: java, sorting, object, arraylist, methods

stuck on a problem with sorting ArrayLists. I'm sure the answer is really easy and something I just keep overlooking, but I've been working on this for the past many hours straight and just need someone else's eyes.

It's a lab project that required us to make 3 custom classes; Applications.java, Rectangle.java, and RectangleList.java and I have to sort an ArratList that contains Rectangle objects with length and width data fields.

The order is (W1, L1) > (W2, L2) if and only if [(W1 > W2) or (W1 = W2 and L1 > L2)

I'm not sure what bits of code would be necessary to look at for help, but I know I'm supposed to use for loops and no outside pre-made methods for sorting. I'm supposed to run a for loop through each index and compare that index to each other index and then switch values. My current bit of code either doesn't do anything (no sorting happens) or it throws up duplicates. Just lots of stuff going on and I've erased everything and started over many times. Not sure where to go from here, and I no longer know how to think of the problem.

Thanks, just let me know what you need to see and I'll try posting it.

Edit note: We aren't allowed to use comparator or comparable or any other compare method I don't know about yet.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
I figured it out!

```java
for(int index = 0; index < (list.boxes.size()-1); index++){
    minIndex = index;

    for(int index2 = index+1; index2 < list.boxes.size(); index2++){
        if((list.boxes.get(minIndex).getLength() > list.boxes.get(index2).getLength()) || (list.boxes.get(minIndex).getLength() == list.boxes.get(index2).getLength() && list.boxes.get(minIndex).getWidth() > list.boxes.get(index2).getWidth())){
            minIndex = index2;
        }
    }
    list.boxes.set(index, list.boxes.set(minIndex, list.boxes.get(index)));
}
```

Comment: you might want to use `Comparable` or `Comaparator`

Comment: Not allowed to. =(

Comment: Unless your willing to write your own sort and comparison algorithm, then a custom Comparator is the general solution

Comment: We have to write our own sort and comparison algorithm, that's the lab, and that's what I'm getting stuck on.

Comment: Sorry the assignment was intentionally made so that you would not use any of existing Java libraries. My advice is to search for sample Java code of different sorting algorithms and modify them for your own case. To keep things simple first get it working with one field only and then add the second one.

Comment: Write `I figured it out!` part as an answer. It is not recommended to write answer in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the comparator could help you :

```
Collections.sort(rectList, new Comparator<Rectangle>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2) {
        if(rect1.width > rect2.width)
            return -1;
        else if(rect1.width == rect2.width && rect1.length > rect2.length)
            return -1;
        else if(rect1.width == rect2.width && rect1.length == rect2.length)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
});
```

If you are using Java8 then Lambda expression can be used to make the code smaller.